# Выбор столбцов из базы данных используя PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

у меня есть база данных, в c++ коде я к ней конекчусь, и далее выполняю SQL запрос :

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(cl.relname) AS table_name, 
                TRIM(a.attname) AS column_name, 
                a.atttypid AS colunm_type, 
                co.confrelid AS foreign_key
    FROM pg_class cl, pg_attribute a, pg_constraint co
    WHERE cl.oid = a.attrelid 
      AND co.conrelid = cl.oid
    ORDER BY table_name, column_name
```

Суть запроса в том, что есть база данных, в ней есть таблицы, я беру и вывожу всё названия столбиков таблиц, а так же вместе с этим вывожу тип столбика и имеет ли FOREIGN KEY данный столбец, но почему-то вместо того, чтобы вывести мне 4 поля (2 раза House 1 owner 1 nope), оно выводит

[image: вот такой вот результат]
 В чём проблема и помогите с более корректной версией запроса. Если у вас есть другая идея реализации, пожалуйста, предлагайте :)

Работаю в PostgreSQL Manager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ найден, дело в том, что порядковые номера столбцов в PostgreSQL нумеруется. Обычные столбцы нумеруются по возрастанию, начиная с 1. Системные столбцы, такие как oid, имеют (обычно) отрицательные номера. Выходит, что я получал помимо моих столбцов кучу других, системных.

Добавив такую правку в конце строки

> WHERE cl.oid = a.attrelid AND co.conrelid = cl.oid ***AND a.attnum > 0***

проблема решилась сама собой